# AwesomeWM - Fullscreen problems (-> videos, wrong moonitor)

Tags: awesome-wm

I have the problem that the Fullscreen always switches the monitor to my left one (nonprimary), even if it was on my right one before.

Also, youtube or other videos I cant even enter fullscreen mode, it instantly exits, with chromium and with librewolf. Any ideas how to fix that? I have pretty standard settings, but maybe I deleted something important from the default config?

I have the default key for fullscreen:

```
    awful.key({ modkey,           }, "f",
        function (c)
            c.fullscreen = not c.fullscreen
            c:raise()
        end,
        {description = "toggle fullscreen", group = "client"}
    ),
```

Also pretty standard rules:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- All clients will match this rule.
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = 3,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                     raise = true,
                     keys = clientkeys,
                     buttons = clientbuttons,
                     screen = awful.screen.preferred,
                     placement = awful.placement.no_overlap+awful.placement.no_offscreen
     }
    },

    -- Floating clients.
    { rule_any = {
        instance = {
          "DTA",  -- Firefox addon DownThemAll.
          "copyq",  -- Includes session name in class.
          "pinentry",
        },
        class = {
          "Arandr",
          "Blueman-manager",
          "Gpick",
          "Kruler",
          "MessageWin",  -- kalarm.
          "Sxiv",
          "Tor Browser", -- Needs a fixed window size to avoid fingerprinting by screen size.
          "Wpa_gui",
          "veromix",
          "xtightvncviewer",
          "Steam",
          "Discord"  },

        -- Note that the name property shown in xprop might be set slightly after creation of the client
        -- and the name shown there might not match defined rules here.
        name = {
          "Event Tester",  -- xev.
        },
        role = {
          "AlarmWindow",  -- Thunderbird's calendar.
          "ConfigManager",  -- Thunderbird's about:config.
          "pop-up",       -- e.g. Google Chrome's (detached) Developer Tools.
        }
      }, properties = { floating = true }},

    -- Add titlebars to normal clients and dialogs
    { rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }
      }, properties = { titlebars_enabled = false }
    },

    -- Set Firefox to always map on the tag named "2" on screen 1.
    -- { rule = { class = "Firefox" },
    --   properties = { screen = 1, tag = "2" } },
}
```

Using this xrandr call on startup:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto -s 1920x1080 -r 60 --left-of DP-4 -s 1920x1080 -r 144
```

Thanks :)

Comment: For the switching of monitors part: If I print c.screen.index before and after going to fullscreen, it says the same index both times, yet the fullscreen image switches the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I totally forgot that I applied that patch from https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/2764#issuecomment-916292655 in order to get GSync running with awesome. The issue got introduced by that, and applying the fix from the linked comment (changing to geometry.x and geometry.y) fixes all issues with fullscreen.